# How to convince Xubuntu 18.04 LTS to put montior to sleep?

Tags: xubuntu, suspend, power-management, lock-screen, screensaver

I use xscreensaver for screen locking. The screen locks automatically as configured. But, recently, my montior has stopped going into power saving mode even though I didn't change any settings. If I run `xflock4`, it will immediately lock and go into power saving mode. But, no amount of waiting will cause it to go into power saving mode. I've tried rebooting and checking for other screen saver programs running (light-locker, gnome-screensaver). How do I convince Xubuntu to put my monitor to sleep?